# Stand-alone (portable) Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, miktex

Sorry for the newbie question, but I just wonder what exactly the files are needed to make `bibtex.exe` and `bibtex8.exe` from MiKTeX being a stand-alone programs.

## Background

The macro `bibtex4word` (written by Mike Brookes) can produce an .aux file containing a list of references being used in a MS Word document. Then it will give the .aux file to `bibtex.exe` or `bibtex8.exe` and then process the output .bbl file.

For using `bibtex` or `bibtex8` on a PC without MiKTeX (with a least-privilege account), I only got 2 choices, either using Portable MiKTeX or installing it under my user account. But neither of both is ideal since I am always moving around plus am impatient to wait for the extraction/installation of that ~150MB file to be finished simply because I only need ~5% of a portable (or basic) MiKTeX.

So I'm trying to list out what files are the dependency files of `bibtex.exe` and `bibtex8.exe`.

### So far

I have used the option of `--trace` plus DebugView (from Microsoft) for tracking, and the files I have come across are

```
miktexstartup.ini  
    - extracted from portable MiKTeX.
miktex-mo-bin-2.9.tar.lzma
    - full extraction.
    - containing initexmf.exe, texhash.exe & mktexlsr.exe .
miktex-kpathsea-bin-2.9.tar.lzma
    - full extraction.
miktex-findtexmf-bin-2.9.tar.lzma
    - full extraction.
miktex-runtime-bin-2.9.tar.lzma
    - full extraction.
miktex-vc100-bin.tar.lzma
    - only needs msvcp100.dll, msvcr100.dll, atl100.dll .
miktex-bibtex-base.cab
    - full extraction.
miktex-bibtex-bin-2.9.tar.lzma
    - full extraction.
miktex-bibtex8bit-base.cab
    - full extraction.
miktex-bibtex8bit-bin-2.9.tar.lzma
    - full extraction.
Some extra packages for different citation styles
```

So far it seems to work fine without giving me any complain when using it in the command prompt of either WinXP or Win7(X64), and the overall size is ~5 MB after compressed and excluding the `mpm.fndb` and `texmf.fndb`.

Because I am fairly new to TeX, I wonder if the files listed above are really the only files which are needed to have a properly functional `bibtex.exe` or `bibtex8.exe`.

Comment: I would just try it: put the files you need on a flash drive and then use a computer without a TeX distribution.

Comment: @seanallred Just triple-checked as you've suggested. Pardon me for recapping what had mentioned in the question: `... it seems to work fine without giving me any complain...`  Off the record, `bibtex.exe from MiKTeX` can still process the `.aux` file expressed with the full-path filename, but `bibtex8.exe` can **not**. Besides, `miktexstartup.ini` is the key for keeping all the setup information & updates within the folder rather then scattering them allover the local machine.